# App deployed on Kubernetes cannot be accessed from Internet

Tags: containers, kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I am new to Kubernetes & Docker. I created a simple nodejs application and deployed on BlueMix Kubernetes. But I am unable to accesses the application on internet. The ip & port mentioned in the kubernetes is not accessible. Can somebody help me.

I tried to http://10.76.193.146:31972, but it did not go through. I am not sure if this the public ip as its 10. series.

I also tried the public ip ( http://184.173.1.79:31972 ) mentioned in the blue mix kubernetes cluster - screenshot below. But that too failed.

This are steps I followed.

1. Created a nodejs app locally. It ran as desired on the local

> ```
> // Load the http module to create an http server.
> var http = require('http');
>
> // Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
> var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
>   response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
>   response.end("Hello World\n");
> });
>
> // Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
> server.listen(8000);
>
> // Put a friendly message on the terminal
> console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
> ```

---------- package.json

> ```
> {
>   "name": "helloworld-nodejs",
>   "version": "0.0.1",
>   "description": "First Docker",
>   "main": "app.js",
>   "scripts": {
>     "start": "PORT=8000 node ./app.js"
>   },
>   "author": "",
>   "license": "ISC"
> }
> ```

2. Created a docker container locally and ran the docker. It worked properly
3. Uploaded the docker container on Bluemix registry as

   > registry.ng.bluemix.net/testkubernetes/helloworld-nodejs:0.0.1
4. Created the Nodes and Services in Kubernetes, using the following YAML file

----------Node YAML file

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: helloworld-nodejs
>   labels:
>     name: helloworld-nodejs
> spec:
>   containers:
>     - name: helloworld-nodejs
>       image: registry.ng.bluemix.net/testkubernetes/helloworld-nodejs:0.0.1
>       ports:
>         - containerPort: 8000
> ```

---------- Services YAML

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: helloworld-nodejs
>   labels:
>     name: helloworld-nodejs
> spec:
>   type: NodePort
>   selector:
>     name: helloworld-nodejs
>   ports:
>   - port: 8080
> ```

5. The application gets deployed properly and is also running, which I can confirm from the logs

[image]
[image]

Result of kubectl get services & kubectl get nodes command

[image: Result of kubectl get services]

[image: Result of kubectl get nodes]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your service's `port` is different from your pod's `containerPort`, you will have to specify `targetPort` in your service.

```
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    name: helloworld-nodejs
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8000
```

According to the Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.5/#serviceport-v1) on `targetPort`, it is the:

> Number or name of the port to access on the pods targeted by the
>   service. .... If this is not specified, the value of the 'port' field
>   is used (an identity map).